# Configuring AWS ALB and Cognito with Rundeck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, reverse-proxy, rundeck, amazon-elb

I am very new to using AWS services. However, I am trying to set up AWS cognito and an ALB to be a reverse proxy for my rundeck deployment. My Rundeck deployment is up and running and working fine. However, I am having issues getting AWS cognito and ALB to sync up. I have the ALB DNS is the call-back url for cognito but whenever I try to access my ALB I get different network errors. If anyone has done something similar, any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In any case, just make sure to set the `grails.serverURL` parameter (at the `rundeck-config.properties` file) pointing to the proxy/LB exit output defined for rundeck. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/5843).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already figured out that you have to configure listener rules on the ALB to authenticate with Cognito and then redirect to the Rundeck endpoint.

To answer your question, the callback URL in Cognito app client settings should look like this:

https://DNS/oauth2/idpresponse

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html